# MVC WebGrid - GetSelectUrl(), GetSelectLink(), and GetContainerUpdateScript() examples?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, webgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

Can anyone show examples of **WebGridRow.GetSelectUrl()**, **WebGridRow.GetSelectLink()** and **WebGrid.GetContainerUpdateScript()** and when to use each? Really had a hard time finding anything on these (anywhere).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using mvc4, only used the WebGrid.GetContainerUpdateScript(string) .

it's to generate a javascript line, can be used at client-side scripting to reload the webgrid through ajax.

the string param is the server api/url

```
string url = Html.ActionLikc(action, controller, whatever-else);
string javascriptReloard = YouWebGrid.GetContainerUpdateScript(url);
@Html.Raw(javascriptReloard);
```

the output looks something like:
$("#ContainerId").swhgLoad("server-url")